# Constructors in Scala

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming

I ran into some design issues in Scala that relate to auxiliary constructors having to immediately call the primary (or other auxiliary)

I think the following example demonstrates the concept

```
class Matrix(args: AbstractRowColumn*) { ... }

class Column(elem: Double*) extends AbstractRowColumn { ... }

class Row(elem: Double*) extends AbstractRowColumn { ... }
```

Here, I think that a Matrix should be constructed by either Rows or Columns.  However, this results in issues because each requires a different set of logic that first must be done before calling a constructor.  (e.i Column must have it's elements processed in a different order than Row before creating the final Matrix)

How do I get around this? Better design?

Comment: If your intent is that the Matrix constructor be passed only Rows or only Columns, it shouldn't accept `AbstractRowColumn*`, since that might be a mixture. (Both answers so far address this.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of Scala's primary constructor is that each class should have a single consistent internal representation, attaching behavior to an (ideally immutable) set of data specified as the class parameters.

Consider making `Matrix` abstract over some basic operations and then making two implementations:

```
abstract class Matrix {
  def get(r: Int, c: Int): Double
  def numRows: Int
  def numCols: Int
}

case class RowMatrix(rows: Array[Row]) extends Matrix {
  def get(r: Int, c: Int): Double = rows(r)(c)
  def numRows: Int = rows.length
  def numCols: Int = rows(0).length
}

case class ColumnMatrix(cols: Array[Column]) extends Matrix {
  def get(r: Int, c: Int): Double = cols(c)(r)
  def numRows: Int = cols(0).length
  def numCols: Int = cols.length
}
```

Comment: You could then add an object Matrix having two overloaded apply methods, one accepting an Array[Row] or Row* and returning a RowMatrix and one Column equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

> each requires a different set of logic that first must be done before
>   calling a constructor.

Sounds like you need a [builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) of some fashion e.g.

```
val matrix = MatrixBuilder.withRows(....).build
```

Comment: I see, kind of saddens me.  I was hoping the class would be able to handle it.  I feel I shouldn't have to declare "withRows", after all I am passing in Rows! >.<

Comment: Then give both methods the same name.